# How can I save this php created image?

Tags: php

What are some possible ways to save an image or make use of it that is generated from a PHP script. Using save as it does not help though.
This is not an image created by me that's why I want to avoid `get_contents`.

*here is the picture*

[image]

and here is the url

https://render01.fontshop.com/fonts/font_rend.php?idt=f&id=38005&rbe=fsifr&rt=how+do+I+save+this?&rs=38&w=500&bg=ffffff&fg=000000&tp=0.0

Comment: Save it on your server or on the useres computer?

Comment: what do you mean by "save"? save it on the user's pc, copy the image data on your server or maintain a reference to this image?

Comment: If "save as" doesn't work, your browser is broken.

Comment: @Juhana please try to save it by yourself before posting please.

Comment: @gion_13 because the image is not hosted on me, I don't want to be listed in their logs.

Comment: Why not save it manually? That way noone will ever find out :)

Comment: @asotshia Works fine with me. Did you remember to change the .php extension to .png after saving it?

Comment: Also, are you asking just so that you can avoid paying the font's licensing fee?

Comment: @Juhana Then I have to apologize. Thank you for this. I will buy it though.

Comment: @asotshia I wasn't asking **why** you want to do what you want to do, I just didn't understood what were you trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the content of the URL to a file

```
<?php
file_put_contents("img.png", file_get_contents("http://render01.fontshop.com/fonts/font_rend.php?idt=f&id=38005&rbe=fsifr&rt=how+do+I+save+this?&rs=38&w=500&bg=ffffff&fg=000000&tp=0.0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function. If you don't have data in variable and want to readout use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Because this is not a generated image by me, I want to avoid any logs in their server. Is `file_get_contents()` appropriate for this ?

Comment: which type of logs ? Code is running on your server and you are sending request to them, not sure if they have implemented logging.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not generating the image in your own code, the simplest would be a combo of `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`:

```
$url = '...'; // your url here
$data = file_get_conents($url);
file_put_conents('image.png', $data);
```

In this specific case the render is a PNG image, but if there's a possibility of it being a JPEG or something else then you need to somehow detect that as well. I 'm not giving any suggestions for this because there's not enough info to go by.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a filename in [`imgpng()`](http://php.net/imagepng) or the other functions to tell PHP to store the picture instead of sending it to the calling browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the terminal using the curl command.

```
curl -o out.png 'http://render01.fontshop.com/fonts/font_rend.php?idt=f&id=38005&rbe=fsifr&rt=how+do+I+save+this?&rs=38&w=500&bg=ffffff&fg=000000&tp=0.0'
```

This will save the file as out.png

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to save it on the client, with a browser, not on the server.

"Save as" worked fine for me (Firefox 7). In Chrome you'll have to specify the extension of the filename manually. Did not test other browsers, but it should work similarly

Answer (score 0):

use imagepng function.

It will return file to browser or save it specified location.
Need to set parameter for function to save image on specified location.